# Unable to attach debugger through Visual Studio to Azure Linux Web Service

Tags: linux, azure, visual-studio-debugging, azure-web-app-service

I have an ASP.Net Core 2.1 web service that I created with Visual Studio 2017 and deployed directly to an Azure Web Service hosted on Linux (Web Service Linux is how it is listed in the creation UI.

The problem is that I can't seem to get the debugger to connect through Visual Studio.  I was able to attach the debugger on my Windows hosted Azure Web Service just fine, but I am getting an odd error just with the Linux machines I need to debug.

I used the Server and Cloud Explorer UI's the select my web service and then selected Attach Debugger.  Works fine with a windows hosted Web Service, but not the Linux option.  It appears it is attempting to connect, but stalls on the phase "Finding process to attach to..." and then errors out with "Unable to find a process called dotnet with arguments .\MyService.dll. The process may still be starting, please try again. (and Cloud Explorer)".

Is attaching a debugger from VS not supported on the Azure Linux Web Services?  Or is there some other step that I might be missing?

Comment: Same issue - did you ever resolve it? Can't find much info anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the same issue with Cloud explorer.
I was able to debug by attaching to SITE.scm.azurewebsites.net. When attaching to SITE.azurewebsites.net I was "connected" but no symbols were resolved.

It will prompt for a username and password, which you can get by downloading a publish profile from azure. Username looks like Site\$Site

Doesn't explain why Cloud Explorer still can't connect, but hopefully that helps. Unblocked me for now